# What is this fancy L with a curl on top, and how could I type it?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, unicode

I have encountered a very strange, L like letter that I couldn't found in the ASCII table, nor in the Greek alphabet. Do you have any idea what this could be, and what its name is? I would like to type it.

[image: equation with the fancy L as a variable]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That character is SCRIPT CAPITAL L (Unicode U+2112), usually seen in by documents typeset with LaTeX for Laplace transforms or Lagrangian mechanics.

`\mathcal{L}` results in: [image: \mathcal{L}].

In macOS, the closest you'd get is searching for the character `L` in the Character Viewer (<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) and looking under Related Characters for SCRIPT CAPITAL L.

It's included in the STIX set of fonts, which comes with MacOS since OS X Lion.

Copying the character results in: ℒ

Comment: The only font (on my system) with a non-convoluted ℒ is Cambria Math (here the bold version: ).

Comment: `\mathcal` uses Computer Modern (CM) calligraphic (or CM calligraphic-bold, depending on settings elsewhere).    To get these "from the horse's mouth", https://ctan.org/texarchive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf and look for cmsy*.ttf (or cmbsy*.ttf for bold), where * is a one or two digit number for the target font size.

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to go to system preferences > keyboard > input sources and add "Unicode Hex Input" you can toggle the "show input sources in menu bar", or bind it to a keyboard shortcut. Then, when you want to type it, hold option while typing 2112, and the L will be typed. You could also configure it in Automator with the recording function and add that to a keyboard shortcut or on the menu bar.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this font: Lucida Calligra
https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-lucida-calligra-f133249.htm

Comment: Good call on knowing an alternate font face. The types Apple ships all make the L very curvalicious.

Comment: @bmike Cheers and I didn't knew that about the stock fonts. 

Comment: When I try to add this font to the fonts I already have on my Mac via Font Book after downloading it, I get the warning "1 serious error was found. Do not use this font." If I continue, then I get the warning "Serious problems were found with these fonts and may cause system problems or even crashes if installed." I did not go beyond the second warning and therefore did not add the font. However, I noticed before trying to add this fond that I had Lucida Calligraphy already installed on my Mac (macOS 10.13.6).

Comment: @Alper Oh! The errors sounds serious :) Have a look at this font manager (https://fontba.se/). It's free and you can enable/disable fonts to improve system performance, specially if you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

Apple products have good support for Unicode. Here is the math block since that looks like a equation:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

Getting these edited in is usually easy one you know what character you seek:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201586
- [What is the quickest and/or easiest way to infrequently type non-KeyLayout provided characters?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329783/what-is-the-quickest-and-or-easiest-way-to-infrequently-type-non-keylayout-provi)
- [How to access Greek symbols on macOS from a basic keyboard without copy/paste?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181328/how-to-access-greek-symbols-on-osx-mavericks)

This may be a “Where’s Waldo” situation if you can’t find a type or font face that blocks the L instead of making it cursive/calligraphic.

Answer (score 1):

It's Unicode U+2112. It's included in the STIX set of fonts, which comes with MacOS.

Comment: Might need to edit this into the selected answer...